# PHP: Controlar Id Row[]

Tags: php

Existe forma de controlar os id's dos dados que vem dos Row[] ?

Exemplo:

Imaginando que quero que ele mostre os dados do ID1

```
$Nome = '<p>Nome: '.$row[18].'</p>' ;
$DataNascimento = '<p>Data Nascimento: '.$row[19].'</p>' ;
$Morada = '<p>Morada: '.$row[20].'</p>' ;
$Email = '<p>Email: '.$row[21].'</p>' ;
```

As vezes ele vai buscar os dados de outros id's e eu quero saber se a forma de contornar isso.
Algo tipo $Row[18].id

Comment: faça `print_r` do array `$row` e coloque aqui um exemplo

Answer (score 3):

Para uma melhor visualização e manutenção recomendo usar o *nome dos atributos* em vez de usar as suas *posições*.

Selecionar os dados da maneira que você quer **$row[posicao][nome]** não é possível a menos que o retorno da posição acessada seja também um array que no caso seria uma matriz!

Se você estiver usando os métodos **mysql_** ou **mysqli_** (*recomendo ler sobre PDO*) em vez de [fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) você pode usar [fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) que permite acessar os dados através dos nomes.

```
$row["id"];
```

Existe a possibilidade de usar [fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) permitindo você acessar +/- como você quer, no caso ficaria assim:

```
$row->id;
```

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)){ 

eu utilizo assim

Comment: então, em vez de usar $row[posição] usa direto $row[nome], ou seja, $row['id'], $row['email']. O nome deve ser o mesmo que retornado pela query. De uma lida sobre mysqli!